# Immigration entry stamp on UK visitor visa

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration

I have Valid Multiple entry visitor visa and I traveled to UK once and at immigration they put the entry stamp on the visa.Will this cause any problem during my next visit and what is the significance of stamping on the visa?

Answer (score 1):

**Will this cause any problem during my next visit?**

No.  All entry clearances are stamped when the person clears immigration control.  It is standard procedure and does not create problems.

**what is the significance of stamping on the visa?**

From the user's point of view, it shows when their UK clock started ticking.  It also gives an audit trail of when they were in the UK (useful in, for example, a   nationality application).

From a control point of view, it establishes that the person entered the UK lawfully and that travel documents were checked again for forgery or impersonation etc.  It also identifies the IO, the port/terminal, and at the IO's discretion, a link to the person's landing card.  It also contains some star symbols used internally, and any handwritten entry codes the IO wanted to make a record of.

Answer (score 0):

I have asked the the entry clearance officer about this. I was told that the first entry into the United Kingdom using a new visa would get a stamp on the visa. I was also told that subsequent entries on an existing UK visa, i.e., already having one stamp on the UK visa, would get a stamp on the adjacent blank page if there is space, else on a nearby page.